dynamic declaration of an include type in a structure in ABAP
I'm trying to dynamically declare or use type define like this (to pass it to a method expecting that type).
  types:
     BEGIN OF TY_ZTEST_123 .
      INCLUDE TYPE ZTEST_ABC.
      INCLUDE TYPE IF_CHDO_OBJECT_TOOLS_REL=>TY_ICDIND.
 TYPES END OF TY_ZTEST_123 .

Because I'm trying to write a generic method to save changes in database tables in cdhr/cdpos
      CALL METHOD (lv_class)=>(lv_method)
        PARAMETER-TABLE
        lt_tab.

I've tried to create a dynamic table using the fieldcatalog.
I've tried by creating a dynamic internal table using the fieldcat and pass it to the method.
  CALL FUNCTION 'LVC_FIELDCATALOG_MERGE'
    EXPORTING
      i_structure_name       = p_name
    CHANGING
      ct_fieldcat            = p_fieldcat
    EXCEPTIONS
      inconsistent_interface = 1
      program_error          = 2
      OTHERS                 = 3.
  IF sy-subrc <> 0.
* Implement suitable error handling here
  ENDIF.

  CLEAR ls_fieldcat.
  ls_fieldcat-fieldname = 'kz'.
  ls_fieldcat-datatype  = 'CHAR'.
  ls_fieldcat-intlen    = '1'.
  ls_fieldcat-domname   = 'CDCHNGIND'.
  ls_fieldcat-ref_table = 'ICDIND'.
  APPEND ls_fieldcat TO p_fieldcat.

  CALL METHOD cl_alv_table_create=>create_dynamic_table
    EXPORTING
      it_fieldcatalog  = lt_fieldcat
      i_length_in_byte = 'X'
    IMPORTING
      ep_table         = dy_table_new.

 ASSIGN dy_table_new->* TO <dyn_table_updt_new>.

But while calling the method, I'm still having an cx_sy_dyn_call_error for the <dyn_table_updt_new>.
How can I solve it, please?

Dynamic creation (means creation at runtime) of data type and dynamic calling are two completely different things. If I understand well your main question, you want to pass any type to a parameter of a method, so you should type it ANY. Please edit your question to clarify it.

How exactly do the parameter declarations of the methods you are trying to call look?

ABAP has a RTTS Runtime type  System.
You can both create a data type and create an instance of data of that type at runtime.
create data docu  to create the data at runtime.
A trivial method to show the concept that should compile.
Although I just noticed cl_abap_structdescr=>create is now marked as obsolete.
So it must have been replaced.
But this still works on 7.53 kernel.
  METHOD dynamic_data.
DATA: lo_struct_descr TYPE REF TO cl_abap_structdescr,
      lo_struct       TYPE REF TO data,
      lt_components   TYPE cl_abap_structdescr=>component_table,
      ls_component    LIKE LINE OF lt_components.

" Define the components of the structure
ls_component-name = 'FIELD1'.
ls_component-type = cl_abap_elemdescr=>get_c( p_length = 10 ).
APPEND ls_component TO lt_components.

ls_component-name = 'FIELD2'.
ls_component-type = cl_abap_elemdescr=>get_c( p_length = 20 ).
APPEND ls_component TO lt_components.

" Create the structure descriptor
lo_struct_descr ?= cl_abap_structdescr=>create( p_components = lt_components ).

" Create an instance of the structure
CREATE DATA lo_struct TYPE HANDLE lo_struct_descr.
ASSIGN lo_struct->* TO FIELD-SYMBOL(<fs_struct>).

" Assign values to the fields
ASSIGN COMPONENT 'FIELD1' OF STRUCTURE <fs_struct> TO FIELD-SYMBOL(<lv_field1>).
<lv_field1> = 'Value1'.
ASSIGN COMPONENT 'FIELD2' OF STRUCTURE <fs_struct> TO FIELD-SYMBOL(<lv_field2>).
<lv_field2> = 'Value2'.

" Output the values
WRITE: / <lv_field1>, <lv_field2>.



ENDMETHOD.

" based on the new docu i tried this instead, and it also worked
" and it isnt marked as obsolete :)
"lo_struct_descr ?= cl_abap_structdescr=>create( p_components = lt_components ).
    lo_struct_descr = cl_abap_structdescr=>get( lt_components ).


Not sure what you are trying to achieve with your dynamics. Here is how you can output an arbitrary typed table into ALV, without declaring separate types within main table type:
SELECT * FROM mara INTO TABLE @DATA(lt) UP TO 100 ROWS.
TRY.
  cl_salv_table=>factory(
    IMPORTING
      r_salv_table = alv
    CHANGING
      t_table      = lt ).
CATCH cx_salv_msg INTO DATA(message).
  " handle error
ENDTRY.

The same approach we can use when passing the arbitrary table into the method:
CLASS lcl_dyn DEFINITION.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    METHODS:  sel IMPORTING tabname TYPE string
                  CHANGING  outtab  TYPE REF TO data,
      out CHANGING tab TYPE ANY TABLE.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS lcl_dyn IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD sel.
    DATA: lo_tabtype     TYPE REF TO cl_abap_tabledescr,
          lo_struct_type TYPE REF TO cl_abap_structdescr,
          lr_data        TYPE REF TO data,
          lt_comp_tab    TYPE cl_abap_structdescr=>component_table,
          ls_comp_fld    TYPE cl_abap_structdescr=>component.

    FIELD-SYMBOLS: <fs_tab>    TYPE ANY TABLE,
                   <fs_struct> TYPE any.

    lo_struct_type ?= cl_abap_typedescr=>describe_by_name( tabname ).
    lt_comp_tab  = lo_struct_type->get_components( ).

    lo_struct_type = cl_abap_structdescr=>create( lt_comp_tab ).
    lo_tabtype     = cl_abap_tabledescr=>create( lo_struct_type ).

    CREATE DATA lr_data TYPE HANDLE lo_tabtype.
    ASSIGN lr_data->* TO <fs_tab>.

    SELECT *
      FROM (tabname)
      INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE <fs_tab>.

    outtab = lr_data.
  ENDMETHOD.
  METHOD out.
    TRY.
        cl_salv_table=>factory(
          IMPORTING
            r_salv_table = DATA(alv)
          CHANGING
            t_table      = tab ).
      CATCH cx_salv_msg INTO DATA(message).
    ENDTRY.
    alv->display( ).
  ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.

START-OF-SELECTION.
  PARAMETERS tab TYPE string.
  DATA: dat TYPE REF TO data.
  DATA(dyn) = NEW lcl_dyn( ).
  dyn->sel( EXPORTING tabname = tab CHANGING outtab = dat ).
  dyn->out( CHANGING tab = dat->* ).

